# Playing a video with captions in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, video, jupyter-notebook, html5-video, webvtt

## How to play a video with captions in Jupyter notebook?

With code snippets from these post, I've tried to play a video inside jupyter notebook:

- [How can I play a local video in my IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019477/how-can-i-play-a-local-video-in-my-ipython-notebook)
- [how play mp4 video in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377185/how-play-mp4-video-in-google-colab)

```
from IPython.display import HTML

# Show video
compressed_path = 'team-rocket.video-compressed.mp4'
mp4 = open(compressed_path,'rb').read()
data_url = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()


HTML("""
<video width=400 controls>
      <source src="%s" type="video/mp4">
</video>
""" % data_url)
```

[out]:

[image]

#### When I tried to add a `.vtt` file as caption, the option appears

```
from IPython.display import HTML

# Show video
compressed_path = 'team-rocket.video-compressed.mp4'
mp4 = open(compressed_path,'rb').read()
data_url = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()


HTML("""
<video width=400 controls>
      <source src="%s" type="video/mp4">
      <track src="team-rocket.vtt" label="English" kind="captions" srclang="en" default >
</video>
""" % data_url)
```

[out]:

[image]

#### But the subtitles/captions are not present when playing the video. How to play a video with captions in Jupyter notebook?

The files used in the examples above are on:

- [`team-rocket.vtt`](https://pastebin.com/raw/Fam4a0Ec)
- `team-rocket.video-compressed.mp4` file can be found on https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IHgo9HWRc8tGqjmwWGunzxXDVhPaGay_?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried loading the VTT file the same way (via data url) you did with the video?

Comment: I've just tried it by streaming the vtt in with the same base64 encoding but it didn't work. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IHgo9HWRc8tGqjmwWGunzxXDVhPaGay_?usp=sharing

Comment: @alvas it looks like Colab is not exposing the right path to the browser to load the vtt files: https://imgur.com/a/DAV7BlP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode

video_path = 'team-rocket.video-compressed.mp4'
captions_path = 'team-rocket.vtt'

with open(video_path, 'rb') as f:
    video_data = f.read()
    video_base64 = b64encode(video_data).decode()

with open(captions_path, 'r') as f:
    captions_data = f.read()
    captions_base64 = b64encode(captions_data.encode('utf-8')).decode()

video_html = f"""
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{video_base64}" type="video/mp4">
    <track src="data:text/vtt;base64,{captions_base64}" kind="captions" srclang="en" label="English" default>
</video>
"""

HTML(video_html)
```

For some reason, explicitly streaming in the video + captions/subtitle while specifying the encoding would bypass the security issues that [@igrinis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75850216/610569) pointed out.

- `"data:video/mp4;base64,{video_base64}"`
- `"data:text/vtt;base64,{captions_base64}"`

Comment: You should add some explanation within your Answer. Otherwise it just looks like a code dump. For example think about: Is it tested and proven to work? How/Why is it better than the other's Answer's logic (you could explain it avoids needing a custom SSL certificate when using a direct VTT file url inside a `<track>` tag... well that's If it even does that?)... Just some advice for a better Answer. Maybe you gave a correct solution but a random code dump with no context/explanation will be harder to win a bounty award. **PS:** Do not reply these words, I will delete this comment soon.

Comment: This works! I'll be good to understand how the streaming + encoding specification bypass those security issues.

Answer (score 3):

It is a combination of security issues. Modern browsers forbid using local data (local subtitles file in this case) and Colab prevents you rendering embedded videos through "insecure" `http` protocol. So in order to display a video with subtitles you will need to create an `iframe` and embed there a video that is served through `https` (both video and subtitles).

You can test this by creating a cell with the following content:

```
%%html
<iframe width="800" height="500" src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/webvtt-example.html"
frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media;" allowfullscreen />
```

So as I see it you will need to create a [self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl), add it to your browser for it to become legit, run a [TLS web server](https://gist.github.com/DannyHinshaw/a3ac5991d66a2fe6d97a569c6cdac534) in a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319268/what-happened-to-thread-start-new-thread-in-python-3) to not block your notebook, create a small HTML file with the `<video>` tag which (the HTML file) your web server will serve over HTTPS and its URL will be the source of the `<iframe>` in the notebook. Whoa, this is really complicated.

---

If we try to load an full HTML into an `iframe` that has the video + track assets stored non-locally, these works:

```
%%html
<iframe width="800" height="500" src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/webvtt-example.html"
frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media;" allowfullscreen />
```

or

```
HTML("""<iframe width="800" height="500" src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/webvtt-example.html"
frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media;" allowfullscreen /> """)
```

[out]:

[image]

But when you try to take the HTML from https://iandevlin.com/html5/webvtt-example.html and load it into the `iframe` through `srcdoc` as follows, it fails to load the captions/subtitles:

```
%%html
<iframe width="800" height="500" 
srcdoc='
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>WebVTT Video Subtitles Example for Chrome</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="webvtt,webvtt example,chrome,html5" />
    <meta name="description" content="Sample HTML5 code that shows how Chrome supports WebVTT subtitles" />
    <style>
        body { 
            padding:10px;
            font-size:80%;
            font-family:verdana, serif;
        }
        figure { margin:30px 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>WebVTT Video Subtitles Example for Chrome</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/06/html5/google-chrome-supports-webvtt-subtitles">Read the full article</a></p>
        <p>To view this in Google Chrome, you must first enable the <code>track</code> element:</p>
        <ol>
            <li>Go to the configuration tools in Chrome by typing <code>chrome:flags</code> in the address bar</li>
            <li>Search for "Enable the &lt;track&gt; element" and activate it</li>
            <li>Restart the browser</li>
        </ol>
    </header>
    <figure>
        <video controls preload="metadata" poster="http://html5multimedia.com/media/elephants-dream.title.jpg" width="422" height="253">
            <source src="http://html5multimedia.com/media/elephants-dream-medium.webm" type="video/webm">
            <track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/english-subtitles.vtt" default>
        </video>
        <figcaption>
            <small><a href="http://www.elephantsdream.org">Elephant's Dream</a> &ndash; &copy; copyright 2006, Blender Foundation / Netherlands Media Art Institute</small>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</body>
</html>' />
```

And taking a closer look at the console following @atalay-k's comment, you will see:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL https://iandevlin.com/html5/english-subtitles.vtt from frame with URL about:srcdoc. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

which looks like a pesky issue from [Security error loading subtitles on HTML video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811082/security-error-loading-subtitles-on-html-video)

Comment: Try changing protocol of the video source to `https` in `<source src="http://html5multimedia.com/media/elephants-dream-medium.webm" type="video/webm">`.